# Updating handleEvent(e) to AWTEvent

Tags: java, event-handling, awt, listener

The first snippet is my first try before I learned it was deprecated and attempted to switch to AWT in the second snippet

```
public boolean handleEvent (Event e) {
    if ((e.target == input) && (e.id == Event.ACTION_EVENT)) {
        try {
            o.writeUTF((String) e.arg);
            o.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            listener.interrupt();
        }
        input.setText("");
        return true;
    } else if((e.target == this) && (e.id == Event.WINDOW_DESTROY)) {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.interrupt();
        setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }
    return super.handleEvent(e);
}
```

The next part I tried below changed it to AWT which is what I'm aiming for but this is when the "cannot be resolved or is not a field" errors came up.I tried processEvent(); but that gave me "cannot be resolved or is not a field" errors on each instance of "target" and "arg", also a "Cannot return a void result" on return super.processEvent(e);. Does anyone know a way I can update this?

```
public boolean handleEvent (AWTEvent e) {
    if ((e.target == input) && (AWTEvent.RESERVED_ID_MAX == Event.ACTION_EVENT)) {
        try {
            o.writeUTF((String) e.arg);
            o.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            listener.interrupt();
        }
        input.setText("");
        return true;
    } else if((e.target == this) && (AWTEvent.RESERVED_ID_MAX == Event.WINDOW_DESTROY)) {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.interrupt();
        setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }
    return super.processEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: Sounds more like you want a `ActionListener` and `WindwoListener`

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).